# Linear algebra square root operator example

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I'm currently reading Axlers Linear Algebra done right 3rd edition and I'm a little confused by example 7.34 and was wondering if someone could explain it to me. It defines square root as: An operator R is called a square root of an operator T if $R^2=T$.

Example: If $ T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{F^3})$ is defined by $T(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}) = (z_{3},0,0)$, then the operator $R \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{F^3})$ defined by $R(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}) = (z_{2},z_{3},0)$ is a square root of T.

Comment: Hint: write down a matrix to represent $T$

Comment: You can use a matrix representation or you can just apply $R$ to a generic vector twice and apply $T$ to the same generic vector once and see you get the same thing no matter what the vector was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $R$ is an operator, $R^2$ means applying $R$ to the answer you get from applying $R$ once. Also clearly, $R$ just sifts the last two vector entries of any 3-d vector to  the left and makes the last entry zero. So

$R^2(z_1,z_2,z_3)=R(R(z_1,z_2,z_3))=R(z_2,z_3,0)=(z_3,0,0)=T(z_1,z_2,z_3).$

This shows $R$ is indeed the square root of $T$.